# How to fetch remote data when no count() is available?

Tags: doby-grid

How can i use the remote fetching functionality of DobyGrid when it is not possible to provide a valid value for the `count()` method?

There are some situations where this is not possible, i.e. when counting all the rows would be way to expensive in a performance point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, it is not possible. The count() is required to determine the height of the viewport's scrollbar which is used for pagination. Without the count, the current pagination technique would not work.

In order to support count-less remote fetching functionality, we would need to add an alternate form of pagination. Either via infinite scrolling which only fetches the next page when you're near the bottom of the grid, or more traditional, with page selections buttons in a toolbar area. We can probably add support for both.

The feature is being tracked on our Github page at: https://github.com/globexdesigns/doby-grid/issues/120